# Unable to execute rake db:schema:dump

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

I am working on a RoR application and trying to set up a connection in my database.yml file to my mysql database. I only want to connect to my development environment as of right now. That db being "simple_cms_development" using the username simple_cms which I granted read/write access.

However I am getting the following error which issuing the `rake db:schema:dump` command:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: config.whiny_nils option is deprecated and no longer works. (called from block in <top (required)> at /apps/RubyStuff/Sites/simple_cms/config/environments/development.rb:10)
DEPRECATION WARNING: The Active Record auto explain feature has been removed.

To disable this message remove the `active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds`
option from the `config/environments/*.rb` config file.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html for more information.
```

For further clarification, my database.yml file:

```
# MySQL.  Versions 4.1 and 5.0 are recommended.
#
# Install the MYSQL driver
#   gem install mysql2
#
# Ensure the MySQL gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'mysql2'
#
# And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
#   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: simple_cms_development
  pool: 5
  username: simple_cms
  password: secretpassword
  socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: #simple_cms_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: #simple_cms_production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

I've also successfully installed my mysql2 gem. Why am I getting this error when issuing `rake db:schema:dump`?

Comment: The error you see is just a deprecation warning, maybe I missed something but the warning point to your /config/environments/development at the 10th line. You need to check that file and change the line as the deprecation message suggest. Concerning the shema, I don't see the error . Have you check if your shema in db/schema.rb is fine?

Comment: I don't see any host line in your database config file have you try adding host: localhost (if the development database is on your local system of course).